# How do I get the value of an element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JavaScript and JQuery and when I select a certain page in my application, an id within the content div named myId shows the string "No results found". This means that when I select the page, the search which is included on every page, executes. If there are records to show, I get these records. If not, then I get the "No results found"-string.

What I want is to check the value of myId and when it is empty ("No results found"), I want to hide some controls on that page.

I already tried `$('#myId').val();` but it just gives 2 double quotes, even if it's not empty.

Comment: How about a jsfiddle.net so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: `$('#id_of_element').val()` to get value of id not sure what you looking for bruv, give some code, cheerios

Comment: @Tats_innit, I like your persona, bud!

Comment: `div` elements don't have values. Do you mean the text in the `div`?

Comment: @NADH you da man as well bruv! :) have a nice one! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to probably do is use the data attribute.

If you have no results found, then do the following.

```
    $('#myId').data('results', '0');
```

When you want to check, access it as

```
    var x = $('#myId').data('results');
```

Check if x is 0, and hide results if true

Comment: You assume that the OP has control over how the search results are presented, but that might not be the case. Just saying. If he has control, why use `.data()` at all? Hiding the elements directly seems to be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text` method to get the content of the element:

```
if ($("#myId").text() == "No results found") {
  // hide some elements
}
```

Comment: While text is a good way of doing it, some of us stopped using it because it brings about a dependency on text. Tomorrow changes have to be made in two places if we have to show '0 results found' for instance.

Comment: @NikhilBaliga: Yes, it would be preferrable to have some other way to check it, but that's what's in the question.

Comment: Thats correct. I want also to limit depedencies, and if I'm checking using the string, changes wil be made at several places, like Nikhil said.

Comment: @hss: Well, that's the only option that you have given. If you know of anything else that you could check that doesn't depend on the text, feel free to share it.